# Optimum usage ratio for broadband

Tags: performance, streaming, bandwidth, broadband

A headteacher I friend has asked my advice regarding how to optimise broadband usage in anticipation of another covid lockdown.The current speed is about 100GB and at peak usage there are about 200 users. I suggested a schedule where priority will be given to essential users (say teachers teaching via zoom, teams etc) then others can be permitted to use the network if performance will not be impacted.

He however asked if there was a general way of working out an optimum ratio of usage combination for a broadband speed. So say if usage types are grouped into "regular browsing" and "streaming", for a 100GB internet speed, what will be the optimum ratio of usage types?

I don't know so I'm asking.

Comment: Can you specify your network speed ? By saying 100GB means literally nothing, is it 100gbps uplink or 100gb/s (direct speed), or is it just maximum line capacity from all users to your gateway ?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that its not 100gb but 1gbps uplink*

*200 users, uplink 1gbps = divided evenly each gets 5mbps (625kb/s direct download speed).
Zoom requires 0.6mbps - 1.5mbps
Regular browsing may vary but should be enough of max 2mbps per device.
At this point you can work out how many users/devices will be in each group.*

Note to mention, upload speeds also play part for zoom conferencing

**To fully know how to divide this better, you would need to know the following:**

- Uplink speed
- Downlink speed
- Physical limitation of hardware (device network cards and switches/gateways etc) as there may be bottlenecks here
- Minimum required speed for Zoom both Upload and Download
- Device/user count
- Device types (wireless/ethernet)
- If wireless, look at Wireless hardware limitations etc as there may be bottlenecks here